# Writing a vector as a linear combination of other vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Write $(-1, 4, -2)$ as a linear combination of the vectors $(0,2,-2)$ and $(1,0,-2).$

Setting up the problem with an augmented matrix then rref it, I obtain:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1 & -1\\
2  & 0 & 4\\
-2 &-2&-2\\
 \end{bmatrix}\sim\to\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

let $c_3 = t$ (there is no leading entry), $c_2 = -1, c_1 = 2$

Thus, $(-1,4,-2)$ can be written as a linear combination for $(0,2,-2)$ and $(1,0,-2)$ in the form $(-1,4,-2) = 2(0,2,-2) + -1(1,0,-2).$

I'm pretty sure I did this correctly, any feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\\-2\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\-2\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$.

Then, by comparing the components, we obtain three simultaneous equations:

$$\begin{cases}
-1 &=& b \\
4 &=& 2a \\
-2 &=& -2a-2b
\end{cases}$$

Thus:

$$\begin{cases}
a &=& 2 \\
b &=& -1
\end{cases}$$